# How to convert Xforms to Normal windows forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress

one of my client have a desktop application which is developed using Visual Studio 2010 (express) and DevExpress . So now he wants to remove Devexpress from the project. is there way to convert it easily?

Comment: For the form itself, you can do a global search and replace and change any public class MyForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm to public class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form. If you are looking to convert the actual DevExpress controls to standard System.Windows.Forms controls, there is no easy way to do it automatically.

Comment: Thank you Brendon.  Are  there no automatic way for that? Then I have to re design it with normal controllers?

Comment: DevExpress controls typically databind to a property called EditValue. You would need to globally replace that to bind to whatever control property is most suitable, like Control.Text. Event handlers would be different as well. This will be a mostly manual process.